# Fire workflow whenever object is created or updated without a rule?

Tags: workflow, workflowrule

I would like a workflow rule to fire when added or updated, but I am not sure of what rule to put. There is no specific rule I need (such as fire when this field goes from false to true). I just need to keep another datasource up-to-date with salesforce.

Is there a go to rule for this situation?

EDIT:

found [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008mlLIAQ)

> Well you don't really have to check for criteria for that.  Just set
>   the workflow rule to "Whenever A Record Is Created Or Edited," and
>   then set some criteria that will always be true, like Created Date Not
>   Equal To .  Then it will fire every time the record is created
>   or edited.

Comment: Use process builder

Comment: Is there anyway around using process builder? I don't want to learn another salesforce technology if it isn't needed.

Comment: Or, otherwise create a workflow rule like owner not equal to blank, so that your rule will always execute, and do whatever you want to perform

Comment: "keep another datasource up-to-date with salesforce" has nothing to do with Workflow Rules

Comment: Opesky, the workflow rule triggers an outbound message that is used to keep another datasource in sync but thanks